# Can't Debug Azure EventHub Function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, debugging, azure-functions

I am having trouble getting a breakpoint to load on an Azure Function triggered by an EventHub event in VS 2019, but when I go to debug the breakpoint never loads. It's stuck in the "No symbols have been loaded..." position

Here is my function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run(EventData[] events, ILogger log)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (EventData eventData in events)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

            // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
            log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
            await Task.Yield();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
            // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
            exceptions.Add(e);
        }
    }

    // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

    if (exceptions.Count > 1)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

    if (exceptions.Count == 1)
        throw exceptions.Single();
}
```

I am trying to debug the `Run()` function by placing a breakpoint at the beginning of that method

Comment: Check the log whether the function is loaded? Or EventHub have been stored message in queue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compiling problem. Try to rebuild it and see if it works. Also,  seems to be you're missing the trigger / connection string info in your function:

```
[EventHubTrigger("samples-workitems", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting")]
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp